# IBM Quickr API: get friendly URL

Tags: api

I'm using the "/myqcs/rest/places/feed" URL to get all places, and I need to extract the friendly url name. I think the only way to do that is to look at the end of the "alternate" link.

For some places, the "alternate" link looks like this:

```
<link href="https://host/lotus/myquickr/driver-competitions-community" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml">
```

but for some, it looks like that:

```
<link href="https://host/lotus/myquickr/!ut/p/c4/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hDC19DY0NfE0P3UBNHA09DY39nJz8Pz9AwU_2CbEdFALQNZ3I!/" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml">
```

So I can't get the friendly url from the second link, there's just a UID.

Why is that, and what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution - when you are an admin, you can make make yourself a site manager, and then the friendly URL is used by Quickr, so it probably boils down to site membership.

Answer (score 2):

For a page to be accessible via a friendly URL both the page and all of its parent pages must have friendly names assigned to them. The friendly URL is made up of all the friendly names in the page hierarchy. e.g. for the URL my/nested/page we have 3 pages assigned friendly names 'my', 'nested' and 'page'. If the 'nested' page did not have a friendly name assigned to it then a friendly URL can not be generated for the 'page' page.

For the pages that just generate a UID verify they have friendly names for their full hierarchy.

If the pages have a full path of friendly names assigned then I think you will need to delve into the Portal Navigation Model SPI and generate your own output, see:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wps/dgn_ptlnavig.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wps/nav_state_spi.html

Comment: Thanks Malcolm, I already checked this and the strange thing is that they do have friendly URLs, I have no idea what separates the ones displaying the name from the ones that do not.

Comment: OK - answer updated (although I concede this is a bit of a cop-out)

Comment: Thanks, I still appreciate the effort - we don't have direct access to the system, so we just use the Atom Feeds. We need the friendly url only for the place, so I don't think the nested pages hint applies in that case.